# How to create skewed axes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create something like this geology visual below that maps soil by its composition (of a given three components):

[image]

To my knowledge there is only `d3.axisBottom()` but nothing like `d3.axis45Degrees()`. So unfortunately my attempts at this visual were cut short virtually right off the bat because I can't even figure out how to set up the axes for a triangular coordinate plane.

### Question

Can d3 handle such an axis configuration, or are there any other d3 methods that would be relevant for a task such as this?

Comment: There may be no `d3.axis45Degree()` but since this is a ternary plot there is the [d3-ternary](https://github.com/davenquinn/d3-ternary) library! Further examples are available as an Observable [notebook](https://observablehq.com/@toja/d3-ternary-plot) based on the latest D3 v5.9.2 or an older yet interactive [Block](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/7674234) based on v3.1.6. @Gerardo

Comment: @altocumulus that's a nice bl.ocks, which can teach OP how to set the circles' coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

This question is borderline *"too broad"*. However, I believe that it's an interesting question, since the documentation may lead someone to believe that only vertical/horizontal axes are possible.

You can always [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Rotate) the axis (any axis, be it `axisBottom`, `axisTop`, `axisRight` or `axisLeft`) and rotate the `<text>` elements back.

Here is a simple demo (full of magic numbers):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([10, 380]);
const axis = d3.axisLeft(scale);
const axis2 = d3.axisRight(scale);
const axis3 = d3.axisBottom(scale);
const axisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(30, 100, 400)")
  .call(axis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-30, -10, 0)");
const axisGroup2 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-30, 108, -378)")
  .call(axis2)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(30, 10, 0)");
const axisGroup3 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(14,333)")
  .call(axis3)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="450" height="400"></svg>
```

Change those magic numbers accordingly. By the way, in that triangle you shared in your question the internal angles are `60` degrees (not `45`), so here I'm rotating the axes by `30` degrees.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that I just *transformed* (`translate`, `rotate` etc...) those axes. For a real plot, like the one in your image, you'll have to create a whole math just to calculate *where* in the SVG the values of the 3 coordinates will fall.